# Get text of cell from table

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

ViewController has table view, one button and label. My task: select any row, then push the button and the text from the selected row must appear in label. **What and how I should to do it?**

I already did familiar code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:@"You've selected a row" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];`

    [messageAlert show];

}
```

In that case you will get a alert message at once you selected any row.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: everybody put minus without comments! :( noobs(

Comment: Keep in mind that your answer had only been up a half an hour before you said that, maybe they would've commented later? Doubtful, but still. xD Also, people on Stack Overflow like it when users show that they made an attempt to figure it out themselves. Make sure you browse Apple's documentation on UITableView and UITableViewCell to get a better understanding of how to use them in situations like these. :)

Answer (score 2):

In `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` retrieve the return value of `[[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text]` and store it in a property. Thus, every time the user changes the selected cell, your property gets updated to the text of the currently selected cell. Then, create a method for the button and wire it up. When the button gets pressed, set the text value of the label in your interface to the property.

---

Inside `@interface` section (it's in the .h file) at the top, put this.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* selectedCellText;
```

Inside the `@implementation` section (it's in the .m/.mm file) put this.

```
@synthesize selectedCellText = _selectedCellText;
```

You now have an instance variable `_selectedCellText` which you can access using two methods. This is called a property. Use `[self setSelectedCellText]` (the "setter") to set it, and `[self selectedCellText]` (the "getter") to get the value. Or, use dot notation and this will be done for you (refer to it as `self.selectedCellText` all the time). Of course, `self` can only be used internally; if another object has a pointer to an instance of this one, you'd use that instead of `self`.

For `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, do this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    self.selectedCellText = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
}
```

Now, at any given time (provided you've properly set up the table) `self.selectedCellText` will contain the text of the cell that's currently selected. So, wire up a UILabel and UIButton, and make the button call a method through target action. If you're using nibs/storyboards, drag them out into your interface. ctrl-drag from the label to your interface section in an assistant editor and Xcode will prompt you to create an outlet; let's name this new property `myLabel`. ctrl-drag from the button to the implementation section, and let Xcode create a method to be called when the button is touched. Let's name it `labelTextUpdate`, and set `arguments` to `none`. Xcode will create the method, so insert this code inside of it.

```
self.myLabel.text = self.selectedCellText;
```

You're done! Whenever the user touches a table, the property gets updated to the text of the label contained in the cell. When the user touches the button, `labeltextUpdate` gets called and the label in the user interface gets updated to the text in our property, which will be whatever text was contained in the cell they selected prior.

Of course, this is providing that I didn't forget anything, since this is from memory. I encourage you to read one of any number of books on Objective-C and iOS/Mac OS development, as well as read through Apple's documentation.

---

I tested it, and it works. Here's the result.

[image: UITableView Usage Example]

I also realized that there's a better way to do this, without a text property or the delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. In the button method, just query your table view to get the currently selected cell, ask for its label, then takes its text and apply it to your label. It should only take a line or two of code and it is much less confusing.

Comment: I must to store the return value from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in prorerty, but how?! `[[[tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text]` where I must to paste it code?

Comment: Declare a property in the header's interface like this: `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* selectedCellText` and create accessors in the implementation like this `@sythesize selectedCellText = _selectedCellText`. You can access the property using `self.selectedCellText`, I'll update my answer with an example in a minute.

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort. I used to read a lot of books about Programming in Objective-C, Mac OS programming, a lot of tutorials on any websites and other before and now. I know everything what you wrote, except how to use`[[[tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text]` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Thanks for that again. I did a lot of simple projects before, but when I tried to do a little harder I met the problem that can't resolve.

Comment: I don't have enough experience for coding without problems, and sometimes I need help from someone, and when people put minuses to your question on any websites and think that you lazy student although I studied a lot books and so on that is offensively... :(

Comment: When I wrote: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    self.selectedCellText = [[[tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
}` I got an error "Use undeclared identifier". I tried create property for that (and nothing :[)... but I shouldn't do that because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not pointer or something that can store data. As I see `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a method name. I also created `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with underscore (_)... Do you know what here wrong? Thx.

Comment: I'll try it in a minute, sorry I was away. It's not a pointer (it's a method call), but the return value is a pointer to a table view cell, so that's what is getting sent the message. When you nest methods so that they wrap around eachother, the outward messages are sent to the return values of the inner methods in sequence. I'll try my code right now to see if I messed up someplace!

Comment: Alright. I tested it (never completed the code) but your problem was caused by my example; I accidentally placed an extra colon and didn't notice. `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` is incorrect; it should be `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`. I'll finish implementing my code to make sure it is all working correctly. I'll update my answer. Also, +1'd your original question to take it out of the negatives.